# Unsubscribe a message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a subscriber setup to subscribe to three topics simultaneously (using message_filters). i want to stop this subscriber. Unfortunately, there is no mention of any "unregister" function in the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/).

How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303373/unsubscribe-a-message_filters.approximatetimesynchronizer/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2018-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally found and answer to this on the [Github Issues](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/380)
Here is an example code of a callback receiving data from 3 topics simultaneously and unsubscribing after 40 messages are received:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import message_filters
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, LaserScan, PointCloud2


def image_cb(depth_img, intensity_img, cloud):
    global subs, counter
    rospy.loginfo_throttle(1, "Receiving data")
    counter += 1
    if counter > 40:
        rospy.loginfo("100 samples, trying to unsubscribe")
        [sub.sub.unregister() for sub in subs]

counter = 0
rospy.init_node("test")
depth_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/pico_flexx_rear/image_depth", Image)
intensity_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/pico_flexx_rear/image_mono16",
                                           Image)
cloud_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/pico_flexx_rear/points",
                                       PointCloud2)
subs = [depth_sub, intensity_sub, cloud_sub]
ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer(subs, 10, 1)
ts.registerCallback(image_cb)
rospy.spin()
```

As you see here, one could just iterate over the message_filters.Subscriber variable and call the  message_filters.Subscriber.sub.unregister() function in order to unsubscribe.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2018-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0